# Incjecting angular grid enterprise

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

I've installed package angular-grid-enterprise via bower. Version of angular grid is 6.2.1. I'm using angular framework in laravel project. This is content of `default.blade.php`, where are stored all necessery scripts.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script scr="http://demos.angularcode.com/grid/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/1.0.0/dist/ng-table.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dashboard/new.controller.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/6.2.1/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
```

And here is my controller

```
var kongres = angular.module('kongres', ["agGrid"]);
kongres.controller('NoviController', NoviController);
function NoviController($scope, $http, $timeout) {}
```

And here is page in witch grid should be displayed

```
@extends(isset($layout)?$layout:'layout.default')
@section('content')
<div class="page-content-wrapper" ng-controller="NoviController">
    <!-- BEGIN CONTENT BODY -->
    <div class="page-content">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 portlet light bordered">
                <div class="portlet-title">
                    <div class="caption font-dark">
                        <i class="icon-people"></i>
                        <span class="caption-subject bold uppercase">Hotel bookings</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="portlet-body">
                    @{{ title }}
                    <div ag-grid="gridOptions" style="height: 600px;" class="ag-blue"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /.container-fluid -->
@stop
```

When I try to load page this error shows `angular.js:38Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]`. My question is how to inject this module properlly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the `<script src="/js/dashboard/new.controller.js"></script>` after loading the `ag-grid-enterprise.js` references

Reorder them like below,

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script scr="http://demos.angularcode.com/grid/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/1.0.0/dist/ng-table.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/6.2.1/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/dashboard/new.controller.js"></script>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/NRLmak)**

Also you have to call this before declaring the module,

```
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);
```

Comment: @user3568043 let me create a sample

Comment: Still the same, but I've found out that when try to load  ag-grid-enterprise.js it fails.` I don't know why, when path is good.

Comment: @user3568043 remove the / from that path